# Business Sabotage & How do I present myself to new hires to avoid being seen as weak?

Tags: employer-relations, anxiety, reputation

I discovered disloyalty (employees trying to do work for clients privately for a lower fee etc.) and most of my 9 employees left either by me firing them (legally; breach of contract) or them resigning. The problem is that when I discovered it, I came across as weak, by waiting and hoping for a turnaround, and not acting decisively and firing the main players immediately.
I generally have a laid back disposition and find it difficult to be curt or aggressive just for the sake of establishing who’s boss. Over time, my disposition led my staff to consider me “weak” and by the time I discovered the disloyalty, my delayed action further reinforced their perception. When I did eventually fire, I had a disgruntled and vindictive group on my hands.

The talent pool for our work is small where I live and they have been able to poison the minds of some potential recruits. I took about 4 new people on a few months ago but they had already been told that I am supposedly weak and they can do what they want, annoy me etc and I will take no steps.

I warned them about this when they came in (my thinking is that better they hear what happened from me than the people trying to sabotage me), but what they heard was firmly rooted in their minds and so they acted accordingly and within 4 weeks, I had to fire them all.

The irony is that despite my disposition, I am not that weak, unassertive guy that can be pushed around. **How do I change this perception so that new recruits will not come in with that attitude? What is the professional method of letting people know you are not to be messed with?**

I currently outsource most of my work but that's not cost-effective and I am anxious that new recruits will come in with the same attitude.

I have no interest in power play or dominance in itself, I just want to know how to get out of this mess where people that I recruit come in with the mindset described above.

Comment: What industry and country is this?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you breed disloyalty by being a terrible boss or just a bad manager in general?

Comment: If you are presenting yourself to new hires as something that you are not, this is also something that people will pick up on. Best thing is to be who you are and build the team around you that complement you. But it is important to recognize that how you present yourself is not always also how people perceive you, so you need to understand why this is the case.

Comment: Perhaps take a step back and breathe? It sounds like your getting a little bit over zealous and controlling about people and their perceptions of you. It might be wise to take relax and do some self-development.

Comment: I believe all you need to do is to pay the new hires good. People come to work for money. If they can make good money, why bother leaving you?

Comment: @scaaahu that's a common, but wrong, way to look at it. Knowledge workers don't come to work just for the money, and if money is all you can offer, most won't work for you for long.

Comment: @Erik In the case of this question, money is the key. The OP's employees left the OP, but still work for the same client.

Comment: @scaaahu that doesn't mean money is key; they just might not like working for OP.

Answer (score 5):

As requested, I'm taking what you've said at face value and assuming you're in the right of all this.  I'm also assuming that your threats of physical violence are an *unfortunate choice of words* and that you wouldn't actually try to solve your problems through fisticuffs.

You could try hiring a recruiter to repopulate your business.  I've seen recruiters who don't disclose the company they're advertising positions for in the initial advert (I would assume it gets revealed later in the process - I've never personally used a recruiter to find a job.)  This would, at the very least, prevent people who are buddy-buddy with your ex-employees from deliberately applying to your company just so they can act vindictively once they get there.

> I took about 4 new people on a few months ago but they had already been briefed that I am supposedly weak and they can do what they want, annoy me etc and I will take no steps. I warned them about this when they came in...

I would also recommend NOT spending time in interview or shortly after hiring someone trying to convince them that you "aren't weak" or otherwise discussing the reasons why you had to terminate your previous batch of employees.  The sooner all that unpleasantness is forgotten, the better.  Also, continuing to harp on the sordid details of what happened with new employees is a great way to make them uncomfortable or nervous, or perhaps goad them into trying their own luck at manipulating you, even if they haven't been talking to your ex-employees.

Just focus on presenting the image you want to portray going forward, and try not to let past events nag at you.  Be confident, but not demanding.  Trying to overcompensate for what happened by "locking down" your new employees is only going to make them resentful and put you in an entirely different position where you have no employees.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you can answer this without knowing the industry or country of the OP.

Comment: Steve-O, thanks a lot. No, fisticuffs is NOT an option. The point I was making is that in some people's world, that would be an easy way to do it but NOT in mine. I guess my question really is what is the fisticuffs professional gentlemanly equivalent of letting people know they cannot mess with you? A recruiter is not an option - when the other 4 joined, our professional community got to know quickly and then my former employees immediately went to work on poisoning their minds.

Comment: If you think in terms of fisticuffs (and I understand you do not intend to use them, just *thinking* in these terms), you are already on the wrong track. Authority is by far mostly non-physical. Entering a direct fight (physical or verbal) indicates, in fact, the break-down of authority that can only be resolved by playing it out in full. This indicates that you are too focused on the power game. If so, people pick this up. It's a bad game to play in any case, but, obviously, you seem not very good at it, either. My suggestion: Stay away from authority games. What do you *really* want?

Comment: @KDCopinger you're trying to recruit colleagues. The idea that you need to "establish dominance" is inherently flawed. You need to earn their respect, and very few people respect "authority through violence", whether physical or verbal.

Comment: @Captain - scrap the reference to fisticuffs. Also, if you read my post again, I am NOT focused on the power game. I am naturally laid back and now have to think along different lines because of the situation I find myself in

Comment: @KDCopinger I respond to "What is the professional gentlemanly equivalent of letting people know you are not to be messed with?" Since you claim you are not interest in power games (which is not obvious, given this your question), I should say: Competence, from the outset. People will not usually begin to mess with you if you establish your competence. However, given that your community seems small and people talk, you may have already lost a lot of authority starting capital. Starting fresh somewhere else may help. If not possible, remember: the boss is the servant of his team. cont'd.

Comment: ... As a boss, your job is to protect your team, make sure it can do its work, give direction, enable them to operate effectively. The boss keeps trouble from the team, defends it to the last to the outside (even if inside it needs berating), does not shift blame around. Gives the team the opportunity to develop and learn, and sends the message that their wellbeing is the bosses priority as much as the team's success. My experience is that such teams can be unbelievably loyal. However, one thing not to do: the boss *is not* the team member's friend. Be urbane, but keep your distance.

Comment: @Captain. Thanks a lot. All sound advice IF I can first get out of the current problem. Unfortunately, leaving town is just not an option for me so I cannot start afresh elsewhere.

Comment: @KDCopinger Knowing the town and industry is pretty important in this case; there may well be people in the next town along who can help..